# Como asignar borde a cellrangeAddress con apache poi?

Tags: apache-poi

Una pregunta, estoy utilizando apache poi y quisiera saber si alguien de aquí sabe como aplicar un estilo de borde a un cellrangeaddress,estoy usando apache poi 3.14.

la verdad tengo poco utilizando esta herramienta, lo que he hecho es:

-asigno en el cellstyle el estilo de borde
estiloCT.setBorderBottom(CellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);

-creo el cellrangeaddress y le asigno ese estilo.

encabezado = fila.createCell(5);
sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(20,20,5,6));
            encabezado.setCellValue(pesogm2);
            encabezado.setCellStyle(estiloCT);

pero solo me lo toma la primer celda.

Alguien sabe como pudiera hacer para que me tome todo el conjunto de celdas?

De antemano muchas gracias por su  ayuda.

Comment: Hola, deberías mostrar que has intentado, que es lo que tienes hasta ahora, que errores te da... Pásate por [ask] y [tour] para mas información.

Comment: Hola buen día, gracias por la observación, ya edité la pregunta haber si ya quedó mejor planteada :)

Answer (score 1):

Te adjunto los métodos que hice para hacer `merge` y agregar `borde`:

```
protected void setMerge(Sheet sheet, int numRow, int untilRow, int numCol, int untilCol) {
    CellRangeAddress cellMerge = new CellRangeAddress(numRow, untilRow, numCol, untilCol);
    sheet.addMergedRegion(cellMerge);
    setBordersToMergedCells(sheet, cellMerge);
}
```

Asignar el borde:

```
protected void setBordersToMergedCells(Sheet sheet, CellRangeAddress rangeAddress) {
    RegionUtil.setBorderTop(BorderStyle.MEDIUM, rangeAddress, sheet);
    RegionUtil.setBorderLeft(BorderStyle.MEDIUM, rangeAddress, sheet);
    RegionUtil.setBorderRight(BorderStyle.MEDIUM, rangeAddress, sheet);
    RegionUtil.setBorderBottom(BorderStyle.MEDIUM, rangeAddress, sheet);
}
```

También hay otro en el que le puedes mandar el tipo de borde que necesitas en el `merge`.

```
    protected void setBordersToMergedCells(Sheet sheet, CellRangeAddress rangeAddress, BorderStyle typeBorder) {
    RegionUtil.setBorderTop(typeBorder, rangeAddress, sheet);
    RegionUtil.setBorderLeft(typeBorder, rangeAddress, sheet);
    RegionUtil.setBorderRight(typeBorder, rangeAddress, sheet);
    RegionUtil.setBorderBottom(typeBorder, rangeAddress, sheet);
}
```